# Choosing with replacement and subsequent sequencing.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

The question I'm facing is a relatively basic combinatorics question, namely:

How many words of exactly four letters can you construct using the letters a,b,c and d?

The straightforward solution is of course 4^4 = 256, as you fill up the four available "empty spaces" with the respective letters, and for each space you have four possibilities.

What I was wondering is how this problem can be solved with the binomial coefficient for choosing with replacement:

$${n+k-1}\choose{k}$$

My reasoning is the following. You have the four letters in a "container", take one out, and put it back (since you can select one letter twice). You repeat this four more times.
The letters you took out must then be arranged in all possible ways to construct a word.

In this sense we would first have $${4+4-1}\choose{4}$$ These are the 35 ways in which one can choose letters with replacement from the four available ones. What I am unable to do is figure out how I can calculate the possible arrangements now, because I don't know how many repeated letters there are in the sample. Is there a way to account for this, to get to the result of 256?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *must* do it the painful way, use [*choose*]$\times$[permute] and add up, thus

*4 of a kind:*$\;\binom41 \frac{4!}{4!} = 4$

*3-1$\;$of$\;$a$\;$kind:*$\;\binom41\binom31 \frac{4!}{3!1!}=48$

*2-2$\;$of$\;$a$\;$kind:*$\;\binom42 \frac{4!}{2!2!}=36$

*2-1-1$\;$of$\;$a$\;$kind:*$\;\binom41\binom32 \frac{4!}{2!1!1!}=144$

*1-1-1-1$\;$of$\;$a$\;$kind:*$\;\binom44 \frac{4!}{1!1!1!1!}=24$, adding up to the expected $256$

Btw, this also shows why *stars and bars* doesn't give equiprobable outcomes